# I get "One of the specified inputs is invalid" on insert raw json into cosmos db

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm trying to insert a raw json into a cosmosdb.
On the last line I get this error, and it's not very helfull:

s: 0; ActivityId: e4f4263c-a23c-4c07-add6-794de42737d6; Reason: (Message: {"Errors":["One of the specified inputs is invalid"]}
ActivityId: e4f4263c-a23c-4c07-add6-794de42737d6, Request URI: /apps/3a32206d-68b5-4fb8-a94c-cf8c807e34bf/services/460b33e3-236a-45a5-ad04-23787bf02678/partitions/45b61407-0b4c-4f2b-b123-18672197c0ce/replicas/133046733022836599p/, RequestStats: Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Tracing.TraceData.ClientSideRequestStatisticsTraceDatum, SDK: W

I have found answers on howto insert an object, but this i just a string. Isn't it possible?

Here is my code:

```
Container container = await database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(
    id: "uniconta",
    partitionKeyPath: "/id",
    throughput: 400
);

var x = await container.CreateItemAsync<string>(jsonCreditors, new PartitionKey("/id"));
```

This is the json that I'm trying to insert:

```json
{
  "odata.metadata": "https://odata.xx.com/odata/$metadata#EmployeeClient",
  "value": [
    {
      "Number": "1",
      "Name": "Carl",
      "Email": "safsd@fdsaf.sf",
      "Hired": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "Terminated": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "UserName": "Kresten Skovsted Buch",
      "UserLoginId": "sdf",
      "Title": "Contact",
      "Invoice": false,
      "Confirmation": false,
      "Offer": false,
      "CostPrice": 0.0,
      "SalesPrice": 0.0,
      "ShowCost": true,
      "ApproveOnEmail": true,
      "TMCloseDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "TMApproveDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "Approver": "1",
      "ApproverName": "kksj",
      "MNENo": 0,
      "RowId": 1
    },
    {
      "Number": "2",
      "Name": "Svend Bent",
      "Hired": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "Terminated": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "Title": "Contact",
      "Invoice": false,
      "Confirmation": false,
      "Offer": false,
      "CostPrice": 0.0,
      "SalesPrice": 0.0,
      "ShowCost": true,
      "ApproveOnEmail": false,
      "TMCloseDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "TMApproveDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "Approver": "1",
      "ApproverName": "kjd",
      "MNENo": 0,
      "RowId": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: When uploadind to cosmos, you should give the partitionKey value, I.E. jsonCreditors.id

Comment: Isn't that just what I do?
I have added the json.

Comment: No - you need to specify the *value* of the partition key, not the *path* of the partition key. Your container's partition key is always going to be `/id` (based on your partition key path, when creating your collection). You need to give that a value, in the call to `CreateItemAsync()`.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. Would my value be "https://odata.xx.com/odata/$metadata#EmployeeClient" ?

Comment: Your value would be whatever value you're placing in the `/id` property (which you omitted in your sample data above). So, for example, if your first doc's `id` is `"001"`, then you'd pass `"001"` as the partition key's value. That would change if you used a different property for partition key, but you chose `/id` as your partition key.

Comment: 1) Your JSON should contain an "id" property at its root level.  2) When you call CreateItemAsync() you need to give the id value of the current json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems here.

- First, you are specifying the *partition key path* instead of the **partition key value** for InsertItemAsync(). This needs to be whatever your value is for the `id` property in your document.
- Second, the document itself is incorrectly formed as it is missing the /id property which is required at the root. And as stated in #1, this value must be set before being inserted.
- Third, you are inserting what appears to be two separate documents in a single insert statement. If these documents are intended to be modeled as a single document I would revisit your model. If these are indeed separate documents (which it looks like these are) these should be inserted separately, removing this oData property. If you need to indicate the type of entity for the data, add a type property such as this for each document, `"type": "EmployeeClient"`.
- Forth, If the `Number` and `RowId` properties are intended to be autoincrement values, this is something you will need to manage yourself. As a distributed database, this isn't something you can rely upon Cosmos DB to do for you.
- Lastly, the use of `id` as a partition key effectively puts every document into its own logical partition (basically using Cosmos as a key/value store). All queries over this data will be fan-out or cross partition queries. This is fine at small scales (<10K RU/s and <20GB). However, this design will not scale. If your intent is this container will grow large over time, you need to revisit your partition strategy to ensure your design will scale efficiently and allow for queries to be performed within a logical partition key value, or a bounded set of logical partition key values. But if key/value is indeed what you want, it is better to use a property that is innate to the data itself and guaranteed to be unique. Something like `UserName`, `UserLoginId` or `Email`. PS: these don't appear in your second document for some reason so maybe something else but something unique.